# How to display data from 2 tables in the same list view in MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been able to bring back the data from the card table I want based on the following SQL Query in my controller:

```
SQLstatement = string.Format("select * from cards, cardcollections where isowned = 1 and cards.cardid = cardcollections.cardid and collectionid = {0}", v.CollectionID);
var CardList = db.Cards.SqlQuery(SQLstatement);
return View(CardList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

If I reference just the Cards model it shows the card listing without the extra data I want. I want to be able to display one column from card collections table (NumberOfCopies) in the same view as though it were included in the first table. If I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it brings back both tables worth of data by appending the columns of cardcollections to the cards table.

I made a view but cannot get it to pass correctly. I get this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[MTG.Models.Card]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[MTG.Models.ViewCardCollectionView]'.
```

I understand that I am not passing the ViewCardCollectionView because of the way I have the CardList variable set. I don't know how to do the query I want while using the correct ViewModel.

```
@model IPagedList<MTG.Models.ViewCardCollectionView>

@foreach (var card in Model) {
    <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=card.Cards.CardID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=card.Cards.CardID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=card.Cards.CardID }) |
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => card.CardCollections.NumberofCopies)
        </td>
        <td>
            <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => card.Cards.Title)</b><br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => card.Cards.MainType.Title) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => card.Cards.SubType.Title)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => card.Cards.AdditionalType)<br /> 
AND SO ON...
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class ViewCardCollectionView
    {
        public Card Cards { get; set; }
        public CardCollection CardCollections { get; set; }
```

I have tried many variations on querying in the controller and trying to bring the viewmodel back in the return View() but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by changing the controller to the following:

```
 var viewModel = from c in db.Cards
                                join j in db.CardCollections on c.CardID equals j.CardID
                                where (j.IsOwned == true) && (j.CollectionID == v.CollectionID)
                                select new ViewCardCollectionView { Cards = c, CardCollections = j };
                return View(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way to handle this would be to familiarize yourself with the [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) and start using that. You're not only writing a lot of excess code you don't have to, but you're opening up your application to SQL Injection attacks by manually building SQL statements based on user input (I'm not sure where v.CollectionID comes from but I would assume somewhere in the app there's a security hole even if it's not right there).